# Google App Script - List all sheets containing

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to list all sheets that contain certain value in a cell.
I used

```
function listsheets() {
var out = new Array()
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
return out 
}
```

How can I introduce the condition to list only those sheets that present "hello" value in the B2 cell?

Comment: Do more research and tutorials. Learn about what the `if` statement does. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#reading_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use small sheets and certain cells you can use

```
function listsheets() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().reduce(function(p, sheet){
    if(sheet.getRange('B2').getValue() === 'hello')
      p.push(sheet.getName());
    return p;
  }, []);
}
```